# How do I convert a database object to int in C#?

Tags: c#, database, type-conversion

How do I convert a database object to int in C#?

```
int uid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["userid"].ToString());
```

Comment: What is the type of the database column? What happens with that code? (Also, if you want to convert it to int, why are you converting it to a string?)

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't convert the object to a string before converting to the int.

```
int uid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["userid"]);
```

If you need to convert a string to an int then use;

```
int uid = int.Parse("1");
```

Comment: 1. C# is case-sensitive. 2. Put four spaces before code to format it as code. Use `>` for quote blocks. More info at the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: @martinho, cheers, I'm not in front of an IDE at the moment to test the code.

Answer (score 5):

Use Null Check before Converting to integer.

```
DataRow row=dt.Rows[0];
int uid = row.IsNull("userid") ? 0 : (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["userid"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Int32.Parse(...)
... - your ToString() method